# Why Couldn't Angel Give Buffy CPR (or Mouth to Mouth)?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buffy - Prophecy Girl [S1E12] — How exactly do Vampires talk if they can't breathe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12036/buffy-prophecy-girl-s1e12-how-exactly-do-vampires-talk-if-they-cant-brea)

This question about [vampires not breathing and not being able to talk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12036/buffy-prophecy-girl-s1e12-how-exactly-do-vampires-talk-if-they-cant-brea) brings up an interesting point.  It reminds us that Xander has to give Buffy CPR because Angel, as a vampire, can't, because vampires don't breath.

But the diaphragm is able to be consciously controlled.  Anyone who sings or has to give speechs or control their breathing in many different activities can tell you that.

Vampires may not need to breath regularly, but they can control their diaphragm with little or no effort.  So why wouldn't Angel be able to provide CPR or mouth to mouth?  Does the diaphragm get disabled when they are "vamped?"

**Note**: This is looking at a different situation than the question I reference.  That question asks about speech, which is an everyday activity that would require constant thought and control of the diaphragm at every moment one is speaking.  While that can be done to a point, it is not perfect and would be ineffective to provide a normal and constant (and consistant) talking voice.  This is about a conscious decision to inhale as much air as possible and force it back out.  It is **consciously** and **for a short time** controlling the diaphragm.  If it seems the same, then try this: Talk to someone for five minutes about anything and see if you can think about and control your diaphragm continuously and consciously.  Then pretend you're giving mouth to mouth, and notice how you control your diaphragm intentionally.

The two are entirely different acts, one of which happens involuntarily throughout the course of normal breathing, the other is voluntarily, and consciously controlled and forced.  Is a vampire totally unable to control their diaphragm consciously?

Comment: This is essentially the same question that was asked in the question you referenced.

Comment: @KevinHowell: No, it isn't, since speech is a continual process, and mouth-to-mouth is a conscious process.

Comment: @TangoOversway what exactly does this cover that the previously-asked question does not?

Comment: @IanPugsley: See my added note in the question.  And try the experiment I suggest.  Involuntarily use of the diaphragm while talking is 100% different than controlling it intentionally.

Comment: I don't see how there is a difference as the answer to the first question will address this question as well. The first question addresses this "More specifically, what I'm looking for is: What method do (Buffy-verse) Vampires use to Speak that is sufficient for them to be clearly understood (and, in fact, indistinguishable from normal speech), yet is insufficient to allow them to breathe to perform CPR."

Comment: @KevinHowell: We (Keith, the asker of that question, and I) are discussing that in chat.  I'm dealing with voluntary control of the diaphragm, which really isn't a factor in speech (unless you're shouting).  There could be many factors involved.  While some questions point out they may have the force to push out air to speak and not do CPR, not one addresses whether they can voluntarily control their diaphragm.

Comment: @Tango I think the answer, either way, is simply: Because it made for a good moment in the story.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: I've addressed, in the text, why this is different than the question that it's marked as duplicating.

Comment: At one point Angel cleans a pair of glasses by exhaling on the lens and wiping them with a cloth. If he can do that, how can he have "no breath" to offer rescue breathing as he claims? This appears to be a mistake/inconsistency within the show with no in-universe answer. The out of universe answer of "because the writer said so" seems to be all we have.