# Has Angel ever inflated a party balloon?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

[Here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12036/buffy-prophecy-girl-s1e12-how-exactly-do-vampires-talk-if-they-cant-brea/12044#comment21983_12044) I asserted that Angel couldn't do CPR as his breaths are too weak.

However, if there had been a scene of Angel inflating balloons for a children's party, then I'd say my answer was bunk.

I've just had a quick look and I can't find any reference to him blowing one up,  but my search wasn't exhaustive.

Does he ever blow one up?

I don't particularly care about taking or normal breathing,  I'm interested in the large forceful puffs of air needed to inflate a party balloon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Buffy - Prophecy Girl \[S1E12\] -- How exactly do Vampires talk if they can't breathe?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12036/buffy-prophecy-girl-s1e12-how-exactly-do-vampires-talk-if-they-cant-brea)

Comment: I'm voting to close as a dupe. Unless I'm much mistaken, you're not interested in whether he's inflated any balloons, you're plainly interested in knowing whether he breathes, something covered by the dupe.

Comment: @Richard No, he's specifically asking whether Angel is able to produce enough air flow to blow up a balloon—i.e., whether he able to _blow_, rather than just expel enough air to make the vocal chords vibrate. The entire point is that he believes the two to be different, which makes this a non-dupe.

Comment: http://www.atpobtvs.com/vampires.html

Answer (score 5):

No, I just recently rewatched all of Angel and Buffy and I'm pretty sure there were no scenes of him inflating balloons. However, I think your premise is wrong--breathing is due to the expansion and contraction of the [muscles of respiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscles_of_respiration) (mainly the diaphragm), and even though he didn't breathe in the sense that these muscles didn't instinctually expand and contract all the time, and his tissues didn't need oxygen (since his heart didn't beat either), he could presumably expand and contract these muscles *at will* with about the same strength as a human, otherwise he wouldn't be able to shout at the same volume as a person.

Comment: Sure, but he did say in *Prophecy Girl* that he couldn’t give Buffy CPR due to his lack of breath.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: There's some debate in the community as to what exactly he meant by that. Depending on how vampire tissues are preserved, it could be something as simple as that the rotting material/formaldehyde/magic dust in the lungs are a bad thing to blow into a living person.

Comment: There's a false assumption in your answer here. Even shouting at the top of your lungs doesn't require anywhere near the amount of quick contraction of the diaphragm and subsequent expulsion of air that is needed to blow up a balloon or even blow out a flame.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Interesting--do you know of a source that says that? Subjectively it feels like blowing out a candle doesn't involve a greater *feeling* of tension in the diaphragm than yelling.